# Making controls on a date

Tags: c#

I'm trying to insert a date on a textbox and making controls (for example don't let the user to put a date which has still to come) but it throws an exception

```
string[] array = txtData.Text.Split('/');
int[] arrayint = new int[3];
arrayint[0] = Convert.ToInt32(array[0]);
arrayint[1] = Convert.ToInt32(array[1]);
arrayint[2] = Convert.ToInt32(array[2]);
try
{
    if (arrayint[0] > 0 && arrayint[0] < 32)
    {
        if (arrayint[1] > 0 && arrayint[1] < 13)
        {
            if (DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Today, Convert.ToDateTime(txtData.Text)) <= 0)
            {
                string s = txtTitolo.Text + ", " + txtData.Text + ", " + txtDim.Text + ", " + txtFormato.Text + ", " + txtRisoluzione.Text;
                listVideo.Items.Add(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("data non valida");
}
```

Thank you to everyone who will answer

Comment: What is the exception _exactly_? On which line? What is your `CurrentCulture`? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: The exception is trying to tell you what the problem is.  Don't ignore it.

Comment: First change, at least this: `catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex); }`

Comment: You're doing more work than you need.  Just use `DateTime.TryParse()` and get rid of the code that is converting the individual parts to integers...

Comment: it gives me the exception on the convert

Comment: Idle_Mind could you post the code please?

Comment: @Fante: `"it gives me the exception on the convert"` - And *what is the exception*?  The first step in correcting an error is to *read the error message*.  Currently your code is *completely ignoring* all exception information.

Comment: make sure your methods arguments are in the right format

Comment: Why not using a [`DateTimePicker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker.aspx) and set [`MaxDate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.maxdate.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
DateTime dateTime;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtData.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
{
    //conversion succeeded, you date is in dateTime var
}
else
{
    //conversion failed
}
```

EDIT:

```
    DateTime dateTime;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact("22/06/2018", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DATE: " + dateTime.ToShortDateString());
    }
```

Comment: it always says invalid date

Comment: what's in `txtData.Text`, exactly?

Comment: ex: 22/06/2018 or 22/06/2012.

Comment: Make sure you have correct data in `txtData.Text` because I just pasted `"22/06/2018"` in my code and it works (look at my edit)

Answer (score 0):

this is how i changed it

```
DateTime dateTime;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtData.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
{
    MessageBox.Show("date has been added");
    string s = txtTitolo.Text + ", " + txtData.Text + ", " + txtDim.Text + ", " + txtFormato.Text + ", " + txtRisoluzione.Text;
    listVideo.Items.Add(s);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("invalid date");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array of acceptable formats like below:

```
        DateTime dateTime;
        string[] formats = { "d/M/yyyy", "dd/M/yyyy", "d/MM/yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy", "d/M/yy", "dd/M/yy", "d/MM/yy", "dd/MM/yy" };
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtData.Text, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("date has been added");
            string s = txtTitolo.Text + ", " + txtData.Text + ", " + txtDim.Text + ", " + txtFormato.Text + ", " + txtRisoluzione.Text;
            listVideo.Items.Add(s);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("invalid date");
        }
```

Comment: it always gives me what i put on the else as a result

Comment: Then your **input** is not in one of the formats listed in the array, or they are in that format but invalid dates (for instance, a day value greater than the number of days for that month).  Make the MessageBox show you the "invalid date" and/or output them to the Console so you can see what is happening...

Answer (score 0):

this is how it looks like right now

```
string date = txtData.Text;
                DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date,"dd/MM/yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                if (DateTime.Compare(dt, DateTime.Now) > 0)
                    MessageBox.Show("data non valida");
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("date has been added");
                    string s = txtTitolo.Text + ", " + txtData.Text + ", " + txtDim.Text + ", " + txtFormato.Text + ", " + txtRisoluzione.Text;
                    listVideo.Items.Add(s);
                }
```

Furthermore whenever i try to print the list in an xls file it doesn't print datas, only other 4 values so it's going to look like: title||size|format|resolution